# wrapping a data grid with a toolbox

Tags: wpf, wpfdatagrid

I got a wpf application.

I want all my data grids in application to have a set of buttons above them.

Tried to use decorator and adorner without success(the dataGrid stopped showing rows)

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given that you're wanting to have functionality behind the toolbox buttons (which I assume will require a reference to the grid) it probably makes sense to inherit from a HeaderedContentControl for this. This does mean that you can put **any** content in the control, but it would be possible to put override the metadata to add validation for this.

Anywhere, here's the xaml:

```
<!-- ToolBoxGridControl.xaml -->
<HeaderedContentControl
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"  
x:Class="WpfApplication3.ToolBoxGridControl">   
<HeaderedContentControl.Header>
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
        <Button/>
        <Button/>
        <Button/>
    </StackPanel>
</HeaderedContentControl.Header>
<HeaderedContentControl.Template>
    <ControlTemplate TargetType="HeaderedContentControl">
        <Grid>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                <RowDefinition/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <ContentControl Grid.Row="0" Content="{TemplateBinding Header}"/>
            <ContentControl Grid.Row="1" Content="{TemplateBinding Content}"/>
        </Grid>
    </ControlTemplate>
</HeaderedContentControl.Template>
</HeaderedContentControl>
```

And the simple code-behind (where you can put your toolbox implementation).

```
public partial class ToolBoxGridControl : HeaderedContentControl
{       
    private DataGrid DataGrid { get { return (DataGrid)Content; } }

    public ToolBoxGridControl()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

To actually use, you can just add the following to your XAML with your data grid

```
<local:ToolBoxGridControl>
    <DataGrid/> 
</local:ToolBoxGridControl>
```